# What does this javascript do

Tags: javascript

window.$ = jQuery = $telerik.$;

To the best of my understanding, there is an Object called $telerik. It has a function $. The function is assigned to the identifiers jQuery and window.$, so we can just use $(args) in our javascripts. Is it correct?

It should mean that we can also use jQuery(args) to find an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $telerik object is given by a set of commercial ASP .NET Web Controls called "[RadControls for ASP .NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx)".

Recently they have included jQuery into the client-side API, and they decided to wrap the jQuery object inside `$telerik` for compatibility reasons.

The code you post is only declaring the `$` and the jQuery objects globally, so you can reference to jQuery by it, and write code as you normally do.

For more info give a look to [this post](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/08-11-26/asp_net_ajax_controls_and_jquery_-_what_about_intellisense.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

it just lets you use $telerik(''); as you would with $('') or jQuery(''); at least, so i believe